# Finding the Laplacian of the deflection potential: I obtain 4(⃗ ), not 2(⃗ ). Why am I wrong?

Tags: astrophysics, mathematics, gravitational-lensing, weak-lensing

[image]

From the review paper Bartelmann and schneider, 1999) [Weak Gravitational Lensing](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9912508), page 48.

---

Like above, the Laplacian of the deflection function is convergence, $\kappa(\vec{\theta})$.

I tried to derive this below, but I obtain 4$\kappa(\vec{\theta})$, not 2$\kappa(\vec{\theta})$.

Why am I wrong?

--Solution process--

Using $ \nabla^2\frac{\vec\theta-\vec\theta'}{\mid\vec\theta-\vec\theta'\mid^2}=4\pi\delta(\vec{r})$,

$\nabla^2\psi(\vec\theta)=\vec\nabla\cdot\vec\alpha(\vec\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}d^2\theta'\kappa(\vec\theta')\vec\nabla\frac{\vec\theta-\vec\theta'}{\mid\vec\theta-\vec\theta'\mid^2}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_V[\kappa(\vec\theta')\nabla^2\frac{\vec\theta-\vec\theta'}{\mid\vec\theta-\vec\theta'\mid^2}]dV$

$=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_V[\kappa(\vec\theta')4\pi\delta(\vec\theta-\vec\theta')]dV=\frac{1}{\pi}\kappa(\vec\theta)4\pi=4\kappa(\vec\theta)$

($\nabla^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 x} +\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 y}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 z} $ , because it's Cartesian coordinate).

---

I realized something, so I write what I realized.

It seems that applying the divergence theorem was wrong.

Because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is open surface, not closed surface(because it is projected image on celestial sphere).

Comment: Might this be better suited to [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Yes, I will do. Thank you.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome astrophysicists know about and use math as well

Comment: @BAO I've added a bounty, but "Why is the laplacian of the deflection function convergence?" is not exactly clear, and in the body of the question you only ask "but I obtain 4$\kappa(\vec{\theta})$, not 2$\kappa(\vec{\theta})$.

Why am I wrong?" Do you think you can restate your question more clearly so it's 100% clear exactly what you are expecting as an answer? *Thanks!*

Comment: @uhoh Thank you for the comment. I will do it.

Comment: Please update your question giving a full definition of the symbols you have used and the coordinate system.

Comment: Yes I did it. Thank you.

Comment: There is a connection to the divergence, if you will. The gradient of $\ln(|x|)$ is the outward normal. By the divergence theorem, the Laplacian (i.e. div grad) of $\ln(|x|)$ in $n$ dimensions is hence the surface of the $n$-sphere times $\delta(0)$. This tells you that it must be $2\pi$ instead of $4\pi$ in your identity for 2D.

Comment: @ntessore Okay, I will think more about your comment. Thank you! And.. Can I ask some trivial question? In Stack exchange, Shouldn't I write "thank you"?

Comment: @BAO Sorry, I wasn't careful when writing the above. It's not the gradient of $\ln(|x|)$ in $n$ dimensions, it's a function $f(x)$ such that $\nabla f(x) = x/|x|^n$. In two dimensions, that's $\ln(|x|)$, while in higher dimensions, it's $|x|^{2-n}/(2-n)$. Then you can show the Green's function property with the divergence theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem here may be that this is a 2D situation.

You say you used
$$ \nabla^2\frac{\vec\theta-\vec\theta'}{\mid\vec\theta-\vec\theta'\mid^2}=4\pi\delta^3(\vec{r})$$
(shouldn't there be a minus sign if $\vec{r} = \vec\theta-\vec\theta'$ ?)
but this is a relationship true only in 3D geometry and $\delta^3$ is the 3D delta function, while $\vec{\theta}$ is defined as a "two dimensional vector, which could be an angular position on the sky" in the review paper.

The equivalent in 2D geometry is
$$ \nabla^2 \ln \mid\vec\theta-\vec\theta'\mid = 2\pi\delta^2(\vec\theta-\vec\theta')\ ,$$
where $\delta^2$ is the 2D delta function.

From there, we see
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla^2 \psi(\vec\theta) & = & \frac{1}{\pi}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} d^2\theta'\ \kappa(\vec\theta')\nabla^2 \ln \mid\vec\theta-\vec\theta'\mid \\
 & = & \frac{1}{\pi}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} d^2\theta'\ \kappa(\vec\theta') 2\pi\delta^2(\vec\theta-\vec\theta') \\
 & = & 2\kappa(\vec\theta)\ .
\end{eqnarray}

As for why your solution is incorrect, I suspect it is the second line.
I don't think the definition of divergence you have used is correct. Why would you equate it with the gradient of the vector? That is not generally true.
I am sure the"proof" is as I have presented it.

Comment: There should be a minus sign, sorry.
I understood most of them. If you answer a few questions, I think my question will be solved.

First, How do you derive the two-dimensional delta function? I derived the three dimensional delta function from 'Coulomb's law'.
(I saw many site related with this like "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932451/how-to-prove-this-relation-between-the-laplacian-of-the-logarithm-and-the-dirac", but I cannot understand)

Comment: Second, If even $\vec\theta$ means <$\theta_1$, $\theta_2$>, Cartesian Coordinate, is it right adding the factor '1/'? I understood the $\vec\theta$ is not theta in polar coordinate.

Comment: How do you derive the 2D Delta function is a separate question (for Maths SE). Second question. I have no idea, you put no definitions of coordinates or symbols in your question, so I am guessing that the definition of divergence is incorrect, or your switch from a 2D to a 3D integral. My derivation is correct. @BAO

Comment: Thank you. I fully understood, so I edit in my question with what I realized. Could I ask one more question? Why did you say "$\vec\nabla\cdot\vec\alpha(\vec\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \kappa(\vec\theta')\frac{1}{\mid\vec\theta-\vec\theta'\mid} \nabla \frac{\vec\theta-\vec\theta'}{\mid\vec\theta-\vec\theta'\mid^2}\ d\theta'^2$"? is the two dimensional divergence's form like $\frac{1}{\mid\vec\theta-\vec\theta'\mid}\nabla$, not just $ \nabla$ ?

Comment: @BAO I am not sure it is correct (other than it seems to lead to the correct solution) and have deleted that part of my answer. However, I don't see why your original version is correct at all. Divergence is not a gradient.

Comment: Okay, your answer is really helpful!